# Could not select images from drawable folder

Tags: android, image

I am trying to add an image slide on my android app.

When I try to add the source for the image, from drawable folder, I can't select the iamges.

Here, a little screenshot to understand better the problem:
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo24x.png)

What can I do to solve it?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Seems like IDE problem did you tried invalidate caches / restart ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to invalidate caches / restart but I have the same problem. Android does not show me the images in JPG, PNG or WEBP format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `PNG` or `WEBP` images as your drawables.

As you may already know variable names should not start with a number. So in your case using a number as your image name forces the compiler to generate a variable named as your drawable name which cannot be accepted in programming, hence the constant `R.drawable.1` does not get generated. Try renaming your drawable to an alphabetical equivalent.

Comment: For first, thank you for your answer. I tried PNG and WEBP also but nothing is changed:
https://ibb.co/dtQN8wq

Comment: Confirm. I was posting the solution. I solved it only changing the name from "number" to "letters"

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

the naming convention shouldn't be a number. declare it in small letters, like this -> image_one ......e.tc.